# Using Laravel 5, how do I get all() and order by belongsToMany relationship by the pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have Deals and Faq's. I have functional relationships working and I can reference $deal->faqs() and it returns the right faqs.

The problem I am trying to solve comes up as I administer the faqs related to a deal. In my Deal admin view (new / edit) I am getting all the Faq's.

```
$faqs = \App\Faq::all();
```

This works great, and I am even able to check if an faq is related to a deal through my checkbox: in the view:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('faqlist[]', $faq->id, $deal->faqs->contains($faq->id) ? true : false) !!}
```

So now we have a list of all the faqs and the correct ones are checked.

I have setup an order column on the pivot table (deal_faq).  That table consists of:

- deal_id
- faq_id
- timestamps
- order

In my form, I have a drag and drop ordering solution (js) built and working.  By working I mean, I can drag/drop and a hidden field value is updated to reflect the correct order.

When creating a deal, this is no problem. Get all the faq's, check a few to associate, drag to order, then save.

When editing a deal, I need to load based on the order column in the deal_faq table.   This is my issue.

I have tried a few things but always get an error. An example of what I have tried is:

```
$faqs = \App\Faq::orderBy('deal_faq.order', 'asc')->get();
```

This returns an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deal_faq.order' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `faq` order by `deal_faq`.`order` asc)
```

I think the issue is that I am trying to get all, but order by a field that only exists for the related faqs since the order field is on the deal_faq. Just not sure how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence you need to join the pivot table and then apply the order

```php
$faqs = \App\Faq::join('deal_faq', 'faqs.id', '=', 'deal_faq.faq_id')
    ->orderBy('deal_faq.order', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

*You may need to adjust table and column names to match your schema.*

Now you can extract this logic into a scope of the `Faq` model

```php
class Faq extends Model
{
    ...

    public function scopeOrdered($query)
    {
        return $query->join('deal_faq', 'faqs.id', '=', 'deal_faq.faq_id')
            ->orderBy('deal_faq.order', 'asc');
    }
}
```

and then use it like this

```php
$faqs = \App\Faq::ordered()->get();
```

**UPDATE:**

> This works to get the FAQ's in order but it only get the ones that
>   have been associated. There will be FAQ's that are not associated and
>   thus not ordered.

In this case you just need to use an [outer join](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) - `LEFT JOIN`. The scope definition would then look like this

```php
public function scopeOrdered($query)
{
    return $query->join('deal_faq', 'faqs.id', '=', 'deal_faq.faq_id', 'left')
        ->orderBy('deal_faq.order', 'asc');
}
```

or a bit more expressively

```php
public function scopeOrdered($query)
{
    return $query->leftJoin('deal_faq', 'faqs.id', '=', 'deal_faq.faq_id')
        ->orderBy('deal_faq.order', 'asc');
}
```

*Please consider adding a secondary order (i.e. by id, or any other field(s) in `faqs` table that make sense). This way you'd have a deterministically ordered resultsets each time regardless of whether you have an explicit order defined in a pivot table or not.*

Comment: This works to get the FAQ's in order but it only get the ones that have been associated.   There will be FAQ's that are not associated and thus not ordered. My question noted I needed all() FAQ's but ordered if there is an order.  Should I also get all the FAQ's and somehow merge the  arrays that are returned to the view so that I can show the un-associated ones as well?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Learning Laravel, just not mysql.